# while threads Creating JMS session ,it is Creating default threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have Multi threading Process, where i am creating multiple threads and assigning to a thread Group.and it is working as expected . when i stop thread  process,my shutdown thread is called  ,and it is waiting ..Shutdown doesnt happing.

i went and check the active count on thread group , and it is showing wierd threads hanging in it.

Please see below threads names.

```
weblogic.timers.TimerThread
weblogic.transaction.TxTimer: '1'
ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'default'
ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'default'
ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'default'
ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'default'
ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'default'
ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'JmsAsyncQueue'
```

Can somebody help why this threads are coming ??